# ConversionService config error

Tags: spring-boot

I am using conversion service in spring boot.
This is my configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class ConversionServiceConfig {
  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  @Autowired
  private Set<Converter> converters;

@Autowired
private ConversionService conversionService;

@PostConstruct
void initConverters() {
    ConverterRegistry registry = (ConverterRegistry) conversionService;
    converters.stream().forEach(converter -> {
        registry.addConverter(converter);
    });
}
```

}

And in the service class

```
@Autowired
private ConversionService conversionService;
```

I am getting the below error:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: mvcConversionService,defaultConversionService
```

Comment: Kindly post your complete exception logs along with other configuration like services & bean definitions etc.